# Clicking the photo then photo goes to detailViewController with Labels at the tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, initialization

What I want to happen is, when I click the photos from the ViewController it will automatically go to the DetailViewController with the labels at the tableViewController below, and the data from the DataSource. and How do I use the Image title as a String in my tableView.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyWfP.jpg)

Codes from DataSource

```
import UIKit

class DataSource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var carsToDisplay: [Car] = []

var image : ImageCollectionViewCell!
var views: ViewController!


override init() {
    super.init()
    //This is the Data I want to show up at my tableView
    carsToDisplay = [Car(name: "Tim", price: 123, image: UIImage(named: "1")),Car(name: "T9m", price: 123, image: UIImage(named: "2"))]

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return carsToDisplay.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    let car = carsToDisplay[indexPath.item]
    cell.imageView.image = car.image
    return cell
}   
}
```

Codes from my DetailViewController

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var savedImage : [Car] = []
    var carsToDisplay: [Car] = []


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return carsToDisplay.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        //How do I put the Image title as a String?
        let car = carsToDisplay[indexPath.item]
        cell.textLabel?.text = car.name!
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I think no-one here is going to analyze your code unless we know what exactly your problem is. Doesn't it compile, what is displayed etc.
First question: Why do you have an image view in your cell prototype when you just want to display the text?

Comment: it's a collectionview above the tableview. the program runs, but the tableview doesnt display the text

Comment: And if you add a breakpoint at `cellForRowAt`, you get hit? What is the content of `car` here?

Comment: post the exact piece of code where you are facing problem, don't upload the complete file. And go through some tutorials to learn about the basic functionalities like navigation to another view controller, passing data from one screen to another

Comment: updated the photo.  please check. the car will be directed to this carsToDisplay = [Car(name: "Tim", price: 123, image: UIImage(named: "1")),Car(name: "T9m", price: 123, image: UIImage(named: "2"))]. 
and I want the name: "tim", price: 123" to be displayed on the tableview below.

Comment: @Cookingcodes: Again: does`cellForRowAt` get hit when you set a breakpoint? What is the value of `car` then? If it doesn't get called: does `numberOfRowsInSection` get called? What value has `carsToDisplay.count` at that point in time

*Anyway*: Why do you use a table / why are your members (`savedImage`, `carsToDisplay`) _Arrays_? I thought you only want to display one car?